# Python 3 how to convert a large number expressed as bytes into an integer?

Tags: python, python-3.x, byte

I have:

```
n = 257
a = n.to_bytes(2, 'little')
a = b'\x01\x01'
```

How can i convert this back into `257`

Also, is there any way to show `to_bytes` without specifying how many bytes?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the complementary [`int.from_bytes`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#int.from_bytes) and specify the byteorder again.

```
>>> n = 257
>>> n_bytes = n.to_bytes(2, "little")
>>> n_again = int.from_bytes(n_bytes, "little")
>>> n_again == n
True
```